# Improving the performance of eigs for a large spd Problem

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

I have two large (think around $100.000\times 100.000$), sparse, real symmetric and positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$ and I want to find the smallest generalized eigenvalue
$$Ax = \lambda_{\min} Bx$$
This can be done in MATLAB by calling `[V,D] = eigs(A,B,10,'sm',struct('issym', 1, 'isreal', 1))`, but the problem is that the convergence is too slow so a lot of large systems of equations need to be solved for an acceptable accuracy. Now this is no fun at all to wait for so I'd like to find a better way to solve the same problem.

Do you have any suggestions? In case you need more context, the Matrices stem from a galerkin algorithm for PDEs. The structure of the basis guarantees that $B_{ij} \ge 0$ and $\sum_{i,j} B_{ij} = 1$, if that is useful.

Comment: Are your matrices actually stored using `sparse`? Have you tried using `eig` instead? The [documentation states](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html#moreabout) that `eig` should be used for real, symmetric, sparse matrices – at least for the basic eigenvalue problem, but possibly the generalized one too.

Comment: @horchler Yes, even 32GB of RAM can't hold a full matrix of that size ^^ I'll try eig as soon as I get home, but I thought it needs full matrices.

Comment: If your matrices are from FEM, consider preconditioning the problem.
$$
M^{-1/2}AM^{-1/2}z = \lambda M^{-1/2} B M^{-1/2} z
$$
If you're looking for an approximate eigenvalue $\lambda_\star$ then $M^{-1}$ should be close to $(A - \lambda_\star B)^{-1}$. Also $M^{-1} \approx A^{-1}$ may work well. You can try incomplete LU to start with.

Comment: @uranix Thanks, I'll try that. eig didn't allow sparse input by the way.

Comment: @AlexR Try `eig(full(A), full(B))`

Comment: @uranix I dont have some Terabytes of RAM ^^

Comment: @AlexR `eig` relies on matrix decompositions (Cholesky and QR afaik) and intermediate results will definitely be full. By contrast, `eigs` searches for eigenpairs in an iterative manner, without using matrices at all, only by computing matrix-vector product, but is much slower.
How much does it take for MATLAB to compute `chol(A)` and `chol(B)`?

Comment: @uranix The Problem is I'll have to use the iterative approach because my memory doesn't fit a full matrix of that size. I'm not faniliar enough with the Lanczos algorithm to know how to accelerate it.

Comment: @uranix Finally came up with a solution. Your idea gave me the hint :) I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, uranix hint with preconditioning lead me to a solution.
The key performance problem comes from solving lots of systems of the form $Ax = b$ with our $A$. Fortunately, $A$ has so many nice properties, that the PCG algorithm works well when using `ichol` as a preconditioner.

Thus using `eigs`' capability to take $x\mapsto A^{-1}x$  as a function leads to this solution:

```
L = ichol(A); % Compute incomplete cholesky decomposition of A as a preconditioner for pcg
n = size(A,1); % eigs needs the size of A if we specify it as a function
[V, D] = eigs(@(x)pcg(A,x,1e-12,200,L,L'),n,B,10,'sm',struct('issym',1,'isreal',1)); % This works nicely
```

`eigs` in my case needed $55$ iterations of `pcg` and each `pcg` needed around $180$ iterations to converge.